# Wordpress Cusutom Page, With PHP,js html and css

Tags: facebook, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I implement a full html,php,js and css page into a wordpress page?
Example:
I have a app.php that has a text box, when You press enter it displays the text with a php echo. With the users profile picture from Facebook.

How Can I inset/implement that into a WordPress page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML/PHP:** The simplest way may just be to create an extra template in your theme. You can view WordPress template hierarchy here: [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

**JS/CSS:** If the JavaScript and CSS makes the most sense to be embedded (it usually does!), you can use hooks and actions in a simple plugin (or potentially your functions.php page) to include the JavaScript and CSS you need.

- [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
- [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

*Note:* I have not personally used functions.php (found in your theme files) to call these sorts of hooks, but I assume it would work just fine.

If you are using a theme that constantly receives updates, it is worth building a plugin to do the job. If not, it's easiest to just modify the theme.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options as far as I know. First one is that you embed the code directly into your posts, and install the plugin called PHP execution. Second, try to create your own [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), and place your own code in the template. then you can create a page in the dashboard and select the template.